# How does one measure the phase of a wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves

Given an electromagnetic wave of unknown characteristics, is it possible to measure its phase? 
Or does it always have to be inferred from interference with another wave (e.g. beating etc.)?

Comment: The phase can be defined only with respect to a reference phase, in other words only a phase difference is a meaningful characteristic.

Comment: it is measured with mixers and as @Maxim Umansky has said it always relative to something *else*, see, http://www.analog.com/en/parametricsearch/10693#/p4781=I/Q%20Demodulators

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By measuring the shape of the transient output envelope it is possible to infer the phase of a pulse of known frequency and length if the pulse is passed through a bandpass filter. You just have to make sure that the filter is not energized before the pulse hits it.